# How to write a constraints on a first nodes for a courier-package problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

We have an employee whose job is to pick up and deliver some packages, and they have each a capacity of C. They can also pick up multiple packages in their route, and packages can be transferred between couriers. To solve this problem, we wish to use the following variables:

$x_{i,j,c}$ which is a binary that equals 1 if courier c travels between $(i,j)$

$a_{i,j,c,p}$ which is a binary that equals 1 if courier $c$ carries package $p$ on the route from $(i,j)$

$g_{i,c,p}$ which is a binary that equals 1 if courier $c$ gather up package p at $i$

$d_{i,c,p}$ which is a binary that equals 1 if courier  $c$ drops off package p at  $i$

We have some constraints, the one relating to these variables are:

$a_{i,j,c,p} \le x_{i,j,c} \qquad $  meaning that if courier $c$ passes $(i,j)$ then he can carry $p$ also.

$ g_{i,c,p} \le \sum_j a_{i,j,c,p} \qquad $ meaning that if package $p$ is gathered by $c$ at $i$ then they must travel to immediate place after $i$

$ \sum_i g_{i,c,p} = \sum_j d_{j,c,p} \qquad $ meaning that if package $p$ is gathered by $c$ it should also be dropp-off by $c$

What I'm thinking on how to write is this one:

How can we ensure that if a courier is carrying a package on a route (i.e. $\qquad a_{i,j,c,p} = 1, a_{j,j_1,c,p} = 1, ..., a_{j_k,j_{k+1},c,p} = 1 \qquad$, then they must have already picked it up at the first nodes i.e. $ \qquad g_{i,c,p}=1 $?

Comment: Wouldn't each package have a known origin and a known destination? Your last constraint, for instance, says that if courier $c$ picks up package $p$ *anywhere* then they must drop it off *somewhere*. It would seem more reasonable to say that $g_{\sigma(p),c,p}=d_{\delta(p),c,p}$ where $\sigma(p)$ and $\delta(p)$ are respectively the origin and destination of package $p.$

Comment: Hi @prubin,thanks. yes that is the case, our courier  can exchange packages with each other in anywhere, that's why I cannot force it over the origin and destination of package. What would you recommend? Is there any better way to put a bound on $y$ and $z$ also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (if route or arc A for $c,p$ is unique)
$ g_{i}^{cp} -1 \le \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} - \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ji}^{cp} \le g_{i}^{cp} \quad \forall i \quad \forall c,p$
If route for employee $c$ and package $p$ isn't unique then M has to be used
$ M(g_{i}^{cp} -1) \le \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} - \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ji}^{cp} \le Mg_{i}^{cp}$

Edit: if a similar constraint for $ d_{i}^{cp}$ is needed then the following may make sense
$ \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} - \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ji}^{cp} = g_{i}^{cp}-d_{i}^{cp} $

$ \sum_c (g_{i}^{cp}+d_{i}^{cp}) \le 1 \quad \forall i \ \ \forall p$
The first constraint ensures (for 1-0: outgoing from node $i$), $g_i =1$, (for incoming:0-1 to node $i$), $ d_i =1$
Next constraint ensures same node $i$ may not be pickp/delivery for same package and also prevents $ g_i=d_i=1$ for 1-1 scenario in first constraint which implies just an edge on the path of pickup-delivery.

Comment: Hi @Sutanu thanks for that. What does that mean? It means, the difference between nodes that a courier is taken should be between its gathering points??

Comment: Shouldn't the second index be $i$? like this: $ g_{i}^{cp} -1 \le \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} - \sum_{i:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} \le g_{i}^{cp} \quad \forall i \quad \forall c,p$\

Comment: That seems to be working  @Sutanu (if you could please explain it a bit more, it'd be wonderful!)  But the problem is that now $d_{i,c,p}$ does not take a correct value. That is,  the  courier drop off is at some others nodes, but the solution output showing different nodes.   Do I need similar things for drop off?

Comment: Basically first index, could be, not always, the index where all incoming is 0. Incoming means (j,i) for node i. First node is where incoming j,i =0 but outgoing (i,j) at least is 1. You already have a constraint for outgoing. So $g_i$ turns 1 only if it's 1-0.q

Comment: thanks again, I cannot figure out why we need to have a upper bound on $g-1$? and do you mean it's not necessary to have something for $d$ too?

Comment: you may drop that if that helps. I put that just in case you have a situation like 0 or -1 (0-0 or 0-1), then $g_i$ is free to take 1. Would you want that? Its upto you.

Comment: thanks again. But I'm confused a little. why we don't force $y=0$ in case where the difference between incoming-outgoing nodes is zero?  like : 
 $ 2g_{i}^{cp} -1 \le \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ij}^{cp} - \sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} a_{ji}^{cp} \le g_{i}^{cp} \quad \forall i \quad \forall c,p$\

Comment: Yes you can do it if it's feasible. But generally we avoid scaling up like using a coefficient like 2 unless required.

Answer (score 2):

The following is only a partial answer, for a reason I'll explain at the end. Let $\sigma(p)$ and $\delta(p)$ denote the source (origin) and destination of package $p.$ Introduce binary variables $y_{i,j,p}$ taking value 1 if and only if package $p$ traverses the arc $(i,j).$ Set $y_{i,i,p} = 0$ for all $i$ and $p.$ Add the following constraints.

- Package $p$ crosses arc $(i,j)$ if and only if exactly one courier carries it across that arc: $$y_{i,j,p}=\sum_c a_{i,j,c,p}\quad \forall i,j,p.$$
- Package $p$ leaves its origin and arrives at its destination: $$\sum_j y_{\sigma(p), j, p} = 1 = \sum_j y_{j, \delta(p), p}\quad \forall p.$$
- Other than at its origin or destination, if package $p$ arrives it must depart: $$\sum_i y_{i,j,p} = \sum_k y_{j,k,p} \quad \forall j \notin \lbrace \sigma(p), \delta(p)\rbrace.$$

You will want similar flow continuity constraints for the couriers (other than where they start or finish, a courier must exit a node the same number of times they enter it).

Now, here is why I called this a partial answer: it lacks a time dimension. You allow packages to be transferred between couriers, and this approach will allow a package $p$ to enter node $j$ via courier $c$ and exit node $j$ via courier $c'.$ What the formulation does not do is ensure that courier $c$ arrives at $j$ (carrying $p$) *before* $c'$ leaves $j$ (carrying $p$). Dealing with the time element will add a whole new layer of complexity (and size) to the model.

Comment: thanks. Does introducing new $y$, means we no longer need to have $g$ or $d$?

Comment: I believe they can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks prof. @prubin and thanks Sutanu. It was very informative to discuss it here.

Comment: Thanks @Atosa. There's an OR site. It's part of stackexchange. It starts with or.stackexchange.com